# R_Multiple plots on same figure using a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, plot

I have 2 data frames, mydf1 and mydf2

```
> mydf1
  id a  b  c
1  1 2 10  2
2  2 3 11  4
3  3 5 12  6
4  4 7 13  8
5  5 8 14 10
> mydf2
  id  a  b  c
1  1  4 20  4
2  2  6 22  8
3  3 10 24 12
4  4 14 26 16
5  5 16 28 20
```

I would like to plot variables a,b & c against id (sample graphs is given below). **I want similar graphs for variables b and c too and I want to do it in a loop and then export it to a local folder.** So, I am using the following code

```
for (i in 2:4) {
    jpeg(paste("C:/Data/myplot",i,".jpg"))
         ymin<-min(mydf1[,i],mydf2[,i])
         ymax<-max(mydf1[,i],mydf2[,i])
         plot(mydf1[,1],mydf1[,i],ylim=c(ymin,ymax),xlab="id",ylab=colnames(mydf)[i])
         points(mydf2[,1],mydf2[,i],pch=2)
         legend("topright",c("mydf1","mydf2"),pch=c(1,2))     
         dev.off()
}
```

My problem is that **I would like to get all three different graphs, (id vs a (mydf1 and mydf2) , id vs b(mydf1 and mydf2), id vs c(mydf1 and mydf2) in one figure.(something like 2 along the first row of the figure and the third one in the second row with legend)** I tried the following

```
jpeg("C:/Data/myplot.jpg")
    par(mfrow=c(2,2))
for (i in 2:4) { 
    ymin<-min(mydf1[,i],mydf2[,i])
    ymax<-max(mydf1[,i],mydf2[,i])
    plot(mydf1[,1],mydf1[,i],ylim=c(ymin,ymax),xlab="id",ylab=colnames(mydf)[i])
    points(mydf2[,1],mydf2[,i],pch=2)
    legend("topright",c("mydf1","mydf2"),pch=c(1,2))     
    dev.off()
}
```

But it didn't work. Any suggestion to do this?
**p.s: This is the simplified version of my task. Actually I have hundreds of columns, that's why I am using a loop operation**

[image]
Sample plot `id vs a (mydf1 and mydf2)` plotted on the same graph

Comment: why not just use `points` several more times?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. I have edited it now. I hope my problem is clear now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is unclear what you are trying to do. Do you want 2 plots, one for `mydf1` and one for `mydf2` or all on one figure? If two panels, you should change to `mfrow=c(2,1)` instead of `c(2,2)` which is currently making 4 panels?

If you want them all on a single plot, then remove the `par(mfrow...` line.

Then within the plots, you are plotting the first series from `mydf1` and the other two series from `mydf2`. Is that actually what you want?

Using base graphics, you should move your `plot` line outside the loop so it is done once,  change the loop to start at 3, and then keep the `points` statements inside the loop. Alternatively, you could put an `if` statement inside the loop to see if it is the first time.

You also have a typo in the plot statement with `mydf` (no number).

And move your `dev.off()` outside the loop so it only closes the figure once.

Here is some code that generates a single-panel plot, and you should be able to modify it to work for your desired output...

```
jpeg("myplot.jpg")
    for (i in 2:4) { 
        ymin<-min(mydf1[,i],mydf2[,i])
        ymax<-max(mydf1[,i],mydf2[,i])
        if (i==2){
            plot(mydf1[,1],mydf1[,i],ylim=c(ymin,ymax),xlab="id",ylab=colnames(mydf1)[i])
            legend("topright",c("mydf1","mydf2"),pch=c(1,2))     
            }
        else{
            points(mydf2[,1],mydf2[,i],pch=2)
        }  
    }
dev.off()
```

EDIT: After your clarified question, I think the only problem is that `dev.off()` should be outside the loop. (I recommend PNG or PDF instead of JPEG for any plot worth presenting....)

```
png("myplot.png")
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
    for (i in 2:4) { 
        ymin<-min(mydf1[,i],mydf2[,i])
        ymax<-max(mydf1[,i],mydf2[,i])
            plot(mydf1[,1],mydf1[,i],ylim=c(ymin,ymax),xlab="id",ylab=colnames(mydf1)[i])
            legend("topright",c("mydf1","mydf2"),pch=c(1,2))     
            points(mydf2[,1],mydf2[,i],pch=2)
    }
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @beroe. Sorry for the unclear question. I have edited it now. I hope my problem is clear now

Comment: In that case, you might just have to move your `dev.off` outside the loop. I would recommend PDF or at least PNG for this graph. JPG will generate artifacts for that many plots...

Answer (score 3):

I'd do something like

```
mydf1$g <- 1
mydf2$g <- 2
d3 <- rbind(mydf1, mydf2)
library(reshape2)
d3 <- melt(d3, id.vars = c('id', 'g'))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d3, aes(x=id, y=value)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = as.factor(g), shape = variable))
```

[image: ggplot example]

or using facets

```
ggplot(d3, aes(x=id, y=value)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = as.factor(g))) +
  facet_wrap(~variable)
```

[image: ggplot with faceting]

to finally export it

```
ggsave(file = paste0(tempdir(), 'myplot.png'),
last_plot()
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Paulo Cardoso. The last one is what I want and it looks nice too. But can't I do it without any package, using the base functions of r? Even a simple plot would be ok for me.

Comment: I'm afraind not. This looks like this exactly because `ggplot` renders this output. Why this should be a problem?

Comment: No problem @Paulo Cardoso. I just wondered if there is a way to do it using the base functions. Anyway Thanks.